OnClick Compose GoogleMap Cluster/Item show InfoWindow without camera move
Using this example activity:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/compose/markerexamples/MarkerClusteringActivity.kt
I want to only shown the InfoWindow when I click a Cluster or ClusterItem, but without the default behaviour to center the clicked item. I suppose I should change something here:
@Composable
private fun DefaultClustering(items: List<MyItem>) {
    Clustering(
        items = items,
        onClusterClick = {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cluster clicked! $it")
            false
        },
        onClusterItemClick = {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cluster item clicked! $it")
            false
        }
    )
}

When returning false, the default behaviour is executed: showing InfoWindow and moving the camera to center the clicked item. But I only want to show the InfoWindow. If I could get the Marker object, I could probably call marker.showInfoWindow() and return true, so the default behaviour is not executed.
